# Angularjs - Accumulate the results of the pagination

Tags: angularjs

I have a paginate layer showing the results to ten a ten:

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="user in users">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6 name">{{user.dato1}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 product">{{user.dato2}}/div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 pos-action">
    <div class="col-md-4 product">{{user.dato3}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 product">{{user.dato4}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need the following: The first page show ten results, but if I go to the next page I have to show  the new ten results and the ten the previous results and so on, for example, the page size three must have thirty registers, but if I come back the page size one must show only ten.

```
/*
 * Function to get data service.
 */
function paintData()
{
    dataIn=getListEventsPdtes.dataIn;
    dataOut=getListEventsPdtes.dataOut;

    if(dataOut.listEvents != null ){
        $scope.users = dataOut.listEvents.event;           
        //Save data in cache
        $scope.cache=$scope.cache.concat(dataOut.listEvents.event);
    }else{
        var text = "An internal error occurred, please contact your system administrator";
        modalFactory.message(text);
    }      
}


function prevPage(){
      if($scope.currentPage > 0){
        $scope.currentPage--;

        var cachedValues = $scope.cache.slice($scope.currentPage*$scope.itemsPerPage, $scope.currentPage*$scope.itemsPerPage+$scope.itemsPerPage);
        $scope.users = cachedValues;

      }
};      

function nextPage(dato, repo){
    $scope.currentPage++;

    var cachedValues = $scope.cache.slice($scope.currentPage*$scope.itemsPerPage, $scope.currentPage*$scope.itemsPerPage+$scope.itemsPerPage);

    if(cachedValues.length == 0){
        $scope.getData(dato, repo);
    }else{
        $scope.users = cachedValues;
    }

};

Thanks,
```

Comment: What's the question/problem? You always want the slice going from 0 to  `(currentPage + 1) * 10`, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

Can u pass the index value to PrevPage when click on paging index 1 2....

```
function prevPage(index){
   if($scope.currentPage > 0){
    $scope.currentPage--;

    var cachedValues = $scope.cache.slice(index*$scope.itemsPerPage, index*$scope.itemsPerPage+$scope.itemsPerPage);
    $scope.users = cachedValues;

  }
```

};